# Access one database from two sping boot applications

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, vps

I have two separate spring boot projects that share one database (MySQL).

Is there a way I can host these two applications on a VPS and make them share the same database the way I make them share it on a local server?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports multiple client connections. Assuming your 2 apps and MySQL are running ok locally, they should all work the same if deployed to the same VPS. If you are deploying across multiple VPS instances then you would need to consider configuring network routes between the instances and firewall rules to allow traffic to flow between them.